# How can we write the below code in magento 2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, magento-2.2.5

How can we write the below code lines in Magento 2.2.5 controller and model?

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('quote_id', $quote->getId())
            ->getFirstItem();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code in your controller or Model:

```
protected $_orderInterface;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $orderInterface,
    .....
){
    .....
    $this->_orderInterface = $orderInterface;
    .....
}

public function getOrder($quoteId){
    return $this->_orderInterface->load($quoteId, 'quote_id');
}
```

Then run di compile and other required commands and test.